# How can I check if all requested values exist in 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, loops

I'm relatively new to C++ and got stuck writing program that manages theater tickets. I tried testing each part of code on it's own to find the problem but couldn't find the issue. I also tried searching for answers but couldn't find any that seemed to fix this. If the user chooses option 2, the TicketRequest function is supposed to verify availability of the seats. If any of the requested seats do not exist, or are not available, an appropriate message should be returned to be displayed by the client program.

I have a few issues with this function:

1. Sometimes it shows seat info (number of requested seats, price per seat, total cost) and it always asks if user wants to purchase tickets, even when seats don't exist.
2. When I request 30 seats in row 15 (max value) starting at seat
3. When some requested seats exist and are available but not others, it acts as if all seats are available but it should show as unavailable if not all are available. Currently, it prints tickets with seat number beyond what exists in the array.

Here are the lines of code for the TicketRequest function:

```
string TicketManager::TicketRequest(int seatsRequested, int rowRequested, int seatNumber)
{
    bool displayInfo = false;
    ostringstream os;

    os << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    if (seatsRequested < 1 || seatsRequested > 30 || rowRequested < 1 || rowRequested > 15
    || seatNumber < 1 || seatNumber > 30)
    {
        os << "\nInvalid entry. The seats requested do not exist.\n";
    }
    for (int count = 0; count < seatsRequested; count++)
    {
        seatNumber++;
        if (SeatStructures[rowRequested - 1][seatNumber - 1] == '#')
        {
            cost = seatsRequested * price[rowRequested - 1];
            displayInfo = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return string ("\nSorry, your requested seat(s) is unavailable.\n\n");
        }
    }
    if (displayInfo == true)
    {
        os << "\nRequested seats:  ";
        os << seatsRequested;
        os << "\nPrice per seat: $";
        os << price[rowRequested - 1];
        os << "\nTotal cost: $";
        os << cost;
    }
    return os.str();
}
```

I pasted the entire program in pastebin so this post doesn't get too long. Here's the link: http://pastebin.com/ZyZskG4S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following:

```
struct SeatStructures[TotalRows][TotalSeatsInARows]; 
with TotalRows = 15 and TotalSeatsInARows = 30
```

Now if the function is called `TicketRequest(int seatsRequested, int rowRequested, int seatNumber)` then following are the valid values for the parameters:

- `1 <= rowRequested <= 15`
- `1 <= seatsRequested <= 30`
- `1 <= seatNumber <= 30`
- `seats will be allocated from seatNumber onwards (i.e inclusive of seatNumber)`

Now, apart from checking valid values of parameters one more checking can be done:

- `1 <= (seatNumber + seatsRequested - 1)  <= 30`

Now, the value returned by function `TicketRequest` can be checked to see if it contains the string "ERROR", since you cannot modify the return value to `bool`.

Here is the function:

```
string TicketManager::TicketRequest(int seatsRequested, int rowRequested, int seatNumber)
{
    if((1 < seatsRequested) || (seatsRequested > 30))
    {
        return string("ERROR: Invalid number of seats requested.\n");       
    }

    if((1 < rowRequested) || (rowRequested > 15))
    {
        return string("ERROR: Invalid row number requested.\n");        
    }

    if((1 < seatNumber) || (seatNumber > 30))
    {
        return string("ERROR: Invalid seat number requested.\n");       
    }

    //seat number should be between [1 and 30] (both inclusive)
    //(seatNumber + seatsRequested - 1) should be equal to last valid seat number
    if((1 < (seatNumber + seatsRequested - 1)) || ((seatNumber + seatsRequested - 1) > 30)) &&
    {
        return string("ERROR: Invalid seat number or number of seats requested.\n");        
    }

    //if you come till here then all the parameters are valid, so just check the availability of seats.
    int cost = 0;
    for (int sn = seatNumber; sn <= (seatNumber + seatsRequested - 1); sn++)
    {
        if (SeatStructures[rowRequested - 1][sn - 1] == '#')
        {
            //seat is available
            cost += price[rowRequested - 1];            
        }
        else
        {
            return string("ERROR: Sorry, your requested seat(s) is/are unavailable.\n\n");
        }
    }

    //if you come till here then all the seats are available.   
    ostringstream os;
    os << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    os << "\nRequested seats:  ";
    os << seatsRequested;
    os << "\nPrice per seat: $";
    os << price[rowRequested - 1];
    os << "\nTotal cost: $";
    os << cost;
    return os.str();
}
```

Now call the function and check the returned value :

```
TicketManager obj;
string szResult = obj.TicketRequest(45, 3, 2);
if(szResult.find("ERROR") != string::npos)
{
    //error
    cout << "szResult << endl;
}
else
{
    //success
}
```

Comment: Your answer was very clear and helpful. I replaced my function with the one you wrote and it ran properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << TicketManager1.TicketRequest(seatsRequested, rowRequested, seatNumber);
```

This line can return `true` value if ticket is available and if it is then you can

```
bool isTicketAvailable = false;
TicketManager1.TicketRequest(seatsRequested, rowRequested,seatNumber, isTicketAvailable);

if (isTicketAvailable)
{
    cout << "\n\nDo you wish to purchase these seats? (Y/N)";
            cin >> confirmation;
   //do whatever you need here
}
```

Function parameters should look like this then

```
string TicketManager::TicketRequest(int seatsRequested, int rowRequested, int seatNumber, bool& isTicketAvailable)
```

Comment: Perhaps `isTicketAvailable` should be `bool` , seeing how `var` isn't a C++ keyword?  Or maybe `std::string`, unless you're suggesting that he modify the function to return a `bool` instead?

Comment: I can't modify the function to return a different data type. It's part of an assignment that requires the function to return a string.

Comment: @user131648 Updated my answer

Comment: @DenisErmolin I used the bool variable you suggested but instead of adding it as a parameter for the TicketRequest function, I set  isTicketAvailable to true in the function when the ticket was available and used that if statement after calling the function. It works properly now. Thank you for your input.